# rbind on data.frames which contains.. 2d "asis" objects in them

Tags: r, dataframe, rbind

Given two identically dimensioned and identically named 1-row `data.frames`:

```
    dn1 <- structure(list(A = structure(list(V1 = 0, V2 = 0, V3 = 0, V4 = 0, 
        V5 = 0, V6 = 0, V7 = 0, V8 = -0.5, V9 = 0, V10 = -0.5), class = c("AsIs", 
    "data.frame"), row.names = 1L), B = structure(list(V1 = 0, V2 = 0, 
        V3 = 0, V4 = 0, V5 = 0, V6 = -0.5, V7 = 0, V8 = 0, V9 = 0, 
        V10 = 0, V11 = 0, V12 = 0, V13 = 0, V14 = 0, V15 = 0, V16 = 0, 
        V17 = 0, V18 = 0, V19 = 0, V20 = 0, V21 = 0, V22 = 0, V23 = 0, 
        V24 = 0, V25 = 0, V26 = 0, V27 = 0, V28 = 0, V29 = 0), class = c("AsIs", 
    "data.frame"), row.names = 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
    -1L))

    dn2 <- structure(list(A = structure(list(V1 = 0, V2 = 0, V3 = 0, V4 = 0, 
        V5 = 0, V6 = 0, V7 = 0, V8 = 0, V9 = 0, V10 = 0), class = c("AsIs", 
    "data.frame"), row.names = 1L), B = structure(list(V1 = 0, V2 = 0, 
        V3 = 0, V4 = 0, V5 = 0, V6 = 0, V7 = 0, V8 = 0, V9 = 0, V10 = 0, 
        V11 = 0, V12 = 0, V13 = 0, V14 = -0.5, V15 = 0, V16 = 0, 
        V17 = 0, V18 = -0.5, V19 = 0, V20 = 0, V21 = 0, V22 = 0, 
        V23 = 0, V24 = 0, V25 = 0, V26 = 0, V27 = 0, V28 = 0, V29 = 0), class = c("AsIs", 
    "data.frame"), row.names = 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
    -1L))
```

If I `rbind` these two, I get an error:

```
    > rbind.data.frame( dn1, dn2 )
    Error in `.rowNamesDF<-`(x, value = value) : 
      duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed
    In addition: Warning message:
    non-unique value when setting 'row.names': ‘1’ 
    >
```

I suspect its due to the "A" and "B" structures in them, I can `rbind( dn1$A, dn2$A)` etc, but since `dn1` and `dn2` are valid 1-row `data.frames` for all intents and purposes, and have identical names and dimesions, it feels odd that I shouldn't be able to `rbind` them.

Comment: This is arguably a bug in `rbind`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the actual reason but I guess that `rbind` doesn't work on this complicated kind of data frame like yours. I come up with a method that achieve what you want as far as possible.

```
> rbind.list <- mapply(rbind, dn1, dn2)
> dn3 <- data.frame(rbind.list)

> dn3$A

#   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7   V8 V9  V10
# 1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 -0.5  0 -0.5
# 2  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0.0  0  0.0

> dn3$B

#   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5   V6 V7 V8 V9 V10 V11 V12 V13  V14 V15 V16 V17  V18 V19 V20 V21
# 1  0  0  0  0  0 -0.5  0  0  0   0   0   0   0  0.0   0   0   0  0.0   0   0   0
# 2  0  0  0  0  0  0.0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0 -0.5   0   0   0 -0.5   0   0   0
#   V22 V23 V24 V25 V26 V27 V28 V29
# 1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
# 2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

`mapply` is equivalent but more efficient than that you use `rbind( dn1$A, dn2$A)` and `rbind( dn1$B, dn2$B)` respectively.

Comment: I disagree that they are complicated. data frames of the type: `d <- data.frame( y= c(...) , x= I( some.array ) )` # are commonly used for things that need doing. that's that this is. I used dput() to dump them here to let them easily be recreated exactly, which causes them to look hairy.

Answer (score -1):

`bind_rows` from library dplyr is more robust and gives a  some clues.

`rbind_rows(dn1, dn2)
Error in bind_rows_(x, .id) : 
  Argument 1 can't be a list containing data frames`

dn1 is a list of two differently structured data frames -- not a dataframe.  Similarly for dn2.

Comment: A data frame can contain lists.

Comment: Yes, but the point made is that the structure is a list of dataframes

Comment: you can use `str(dn1)` and `class(dn1)` to see that `dn1` is a kind of `data.frame`. So is `dn2`.

Comment: I think what the OP want to do is `rbind(dn1$A, dn2$A)` and `rbind(dn1$B, dn2$B)` respectively, not rbind all their elements.

Comment: dn1 and dn2 were originally created with a call to `data.frame( A=I(...), B=I(...) )` # I then used dput to easily generate code to recreate them identicaly. I wanted to rbind() on the entire thing. having I(...) elements in a data.frame is fairly common if you do eg. multivariate analysis using formulas.

Comment: Some searching yielded https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/2962 "bind_rows rejects lists with additional class names" 
OP used rbind so this may not directly relate, but the bind_rows issue may have similar roots.